# How to write this query for better performance in Sql Server? Removing SubString rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance

How to write this query for better performance?

```
SELECT T1.flow
FROM #allflows T1 INNER JOIN
     #allflows T2
     ON t2.flow like t1.flow + '%'
```

Comment: can you please sahre your  sample data and expected output

Comment: It might be better to take a step back and think about what the aim of the query is - you are selecting all rows from the table then self-joining to any rows that match on your 'like' condition - what are you using the table for?   You will be selecting all rows at least once i think, and you could be selecting up to 'n-squared' rows

Comment: Downvoted for not properly editing the question and adding new available information to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own representative '#allflows' by querying a sample customer table, 30,000 rows

here's what I got

```
Declare @s as datetime = getdate();


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_tempNCIndexAft ON #allflows (flow);

SELECT 'make index', DATEDIff(second,@s, getdate())

SET @s = getdate();

SELECT t1.flow,COUNT(DISTINCT t2.flow) cnt INTO #realflows FROM #allflows t1 
                INNER JOIN #allflows t2 ON t2.flow like t1.flow+ '%' GROUP BY t1.flow HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.flow) = 1;


SELECT 'your query', DATEDIff(second,@s, getdate())

    select * from #realflows ;
```

Comment: 30000 is NOT very large. It is not even small. Around 1995 or so Foxpro had no problems dealing with 1 million rows in a query.

Comment: @TomTom - I can go and get more rows if you like.  What point are you making here though?  I didn't call it 'ver large' or 'very small' The questioner mentioned 60,000 rows - I quickly put half that size up and got 2 mins down by a lot, I doubt if my 30K versus his 60K is a big deal - in any case I'm providing free help, I'm not exactly replicating his circumstance

Comment: ok I did call my table 'large' - as it was actually from a 'large company' - please feel free to add your own FoxPro solution though.

Comment: I could make two tables now, one with a billion records in it, then make a query with no problems in it, but I could also come up with a table with ten records in it, and devise a query with a performance problem.  In this case he has 60K records, and a performance problem - it isn't the size of his table making the problem

Comment: Or you jsut remove the statement large, which is delusional.

Comment: @Cato: Thank you so much for your efforts in looking into this. Putting index has given very much improvement on performance. 
Thanks to reminding me once again that solution lies in basic steps. Much appreciated.

Comment: thank you - I was surprised that the indexing method gave an improvement - I'm pleased to have helped

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want duplicates, so you can just do:

```
select t1.flow
from #allflows t1
where t1.flow is not null;
```

Why?  Well `t1.flow` is going to match `like t1.flow + '%'`.

Of course, if you *want* the duplicates, then the query is more expensive.

My guess is that this does not necessarily answer your question.  You should ask *another* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: but wait, by adding an index to a temp table with 37K records, I got the time down to 100's of milliseconds  - unless I'm missing something to do with caching.  He put some more info about his query in Ajan's answer's comments section

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the query by selecting only the necessary columns before joining in this case

```
SELECT T1.flow FROM #allflows T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT flow from #allflows) T2 ON t2.flow like t1.flow + '%'
```

Comment: That will do nothing to improve the query. The execution plan will be identical.

Comment: FYI: This temp table has only 1 column [flow]

Comment: what is the query for, and how many rows does it end up returning?

Comment: @Cato: This query is to check if column value is substring of any other row.
Full query is here
SELECT t1.flow
INTO #realflows
FROM #allflows t1
  INNER JOIN #allflows t2 ON t2.flow like t1.flow + '%'
GROUP BY t1.flow
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.flow) = 1

Comment: @Cato: It has 60000+ records

Comment: so it is also returning itself, as a substring of itself?  You only return rows that are not a substring of any other row?

Comment: @Cato: Yes. This query returns the required result. But query is taking almost 5 min to execute this. So finding better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please summarise and add all of this new information to the original question